# TLD Parse error on deploying EAR to JBoss AS7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy a EAR which runs on  Websphere6.1 on JBoss AS7 but i'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class org.jboss.metadata.web.spec.BodyContentType.None
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_29]
        at or.jboss.metadata.web.spec.BodyContentType.valueOf(BodyContentType.java:30)
        at org.jboss.metadata.parser.jsp.TagMetaDataParser.parse(TagMetaDataParser.java:117)
        at org.jboss.metadata.parser.jsp.TldMetaDataParser.parse(TldMetaDataParser.java:226)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.parseTLD(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:124)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.processTlds(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:105)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        ... 5 more
```

I can't tell which .tld file it's trying to parse but I've looked at the .tld files in the WAR and the ones which specify a `<body-content>` tag are `<body-content>scriptless</body-content>`. All the .tld files have this doctype:

`<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">`

Has any body come across this or a similar problem?

[edit]

I've added a `<body-content>` tag to each tag in the tld files but i'm still getting this error - so I guess it's trying to parse some other .tld ...

... and removing all the .tld files from the EAR gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the jars in WEB-INF lib folder (you know who you are, spring-modules-validation.jar v.0.9) has a .tld which specifies `<body-content>None</body-content>` for `org.springmodules.validation.valang.javascript.taglib.ValangCodebaseTag`

Comment: I suppose None is wrong value. What are possible valid values?

Answer (score 3):

check whether the spring-modules-validation-0.8.jar. 
META-INF/valang.tld contains invalid body-content value.

i.e, 
`<body-content>None</body-content>` where the value "None" is not valid. Replace this value with "empty".

So the correct tag is
`<body-content>empty</body-content>`

Jboss-7.x will not deploy applications bundling the SpringModules library with this incorrect file in it (SPRINGMODULES-13).

Comment: I guess I was just too subtle with the answer to my own question.

Comment: enum org.jboss.metadata.web.spec.BodyContentType contains the following values "tagdependent, JSP, empty, scriptless" and its case sensitve this error occured for JSP and empty in my case thanks @mohammed aslam