# Using spring-modules-validation with Wildfly/JBoss - the tld validation issue

Tags: spring, jboss, wildfly, spring-modules

I am trying to use spring-modules-validation in a project deployed on a JBoss server, and i have this issue: [TLD Parse error on deploying EAR to JBoss AS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226916/tld-parse-error-on-deploying-ear-to-jboss-as7)
The solution is quite clear, however i manage my dependencies with Maven, and so i can't easily modify the tld in question.

I thought about using it as a jar,modifying the tld, and deploy it locally, but i'm unconfortable with the idea. Also, i imagine it has its own dependencies which i will have also to move locally ... and so on.

Anyone has a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: see discussion here https://developer.jboss.org/thread/250990

Answer (score 0):

In the end i included the spring module as a pom, with all its dependencies and that's it.

Comment: Can you provide more details?